# Getting Error when accessing SSRS through browser

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I get the error message below when accessing Reporting Services through a browser

URL used: `http://<name of server>/ReportServer`

> Reporting Services Error
>
> ---
>
> The report server cannot open a connection to the report server
>   database. A connection to the database is required for all requests
>   and processing. (rsReportServerDatabaseUnavailable) Get Online Help A
>   network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing
>   a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not
>   accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL
>   Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named
>   Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)
>
> ---

Answer (score 1):

Have you verified that the configuration is correct? Use "Reporting Service Configuration Manager" which is installed with SSRS. Step through the screens looking for problems; try applying the configuration and make sure databases exist and have correct permissions.

Answer (score 0):

Try running RSConfigTool.exe or Report Services Configuration Manager from Windows and check if the server is accessible